# multiselector search in ExtJS Kitchensink

Tags: css, extjs, gridview, multi-select

I have modified the Multi-Selector Grid under the Form Fields menu option in the extJS Kitchensink example (http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#multi-selector).

```
        var ms = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            xtype: 'multi-selector',
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            requires: [
                'Ext.view.MultiSelector'
            ],
            layout: 'fit',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'multiselector',
                title: 'Selected Dx',

                fieldName: 'string_value',

                viewConfig: {
                    deferEmptyText: false,
                    emptyText: 'No Dx selected'
                },

                search: {
                    field: 'string_value',

                    store: {
                        fields: [
                            {
                                name: 'string_value',
                                type: 'string'
                            }
                        ],
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/factor',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: '0'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }).center();


    });
}
```

It works, for the most part, but when I click on the search button, it looks like this:

[image: My Multi-Selector Search box]

as opposed to the one in Kitchensink, which looks like:

[image: Kitchensink version of Search Box]

As you see, the Kitchensink search box has the check boxes in from of the listed items, while mine doesn't. Thus, I am unable to select multiple items.

I figured this was due to a missing CSS file, but other than the kitchensink css file, I am not sure what to use.

For what it's worth, when I hover over

xtype: 'multi-selector',

in WebStorm, I get a message that "Ext JS class for type 'multi-selector' not found"

Comment: An xtype is basically an alias for an ExtJS class.  If you're creating a component using Ext.create you're specifying the class already - there's no need for the xtype.  So in this case, `Ext.create('Ext.container.Container'` creates a container no matter what xtype you specify.  In the KitchenSink example they are *defining* a class, and they are giving it an alias/xtype of 'multi-selector'.  Since you don't include that code anywhere WebStorm doesn't know what a 'multi-selector' is.
Still, code looks okay and I would think it is a CSS issue.  Does it allow you to select the items at all?

Comment: Yep, I figured out the bit about removing the extraneous xtype. Yes, it allows me to select multiple items, but of course without the checkboxes, hitting the right spot with the cursor is an issue. When I find the solution, I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sho' 'nuf: Added `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"/>` to index.html, did a "sencha app build" and all is well!

See here: [image: Correct output with checkboxes]

Interestingly, when I uncheck the items from the search list, they do not get removed from the selected pane.

See here: [image: Unchecked]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found a workaround, but whenever you're 
'requiring' a new ExtJS component for the first time in your application, you need to run 'sencha app refresh' (or run a build like you did) so the microloader knows to also pull in the styles for said component.